# Is there a way to have a Excel file attached to Visual C# project without the need of always having the correct directory location?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to work on a project and still fairly fresh with coding. I need to open a Excel file that I have made as a template to making copies, but when done I want it to have the Excel file as a part of the program so you could technically take the project files where ever you go. It is writing data to file (not reading and pulling data) so I want it to be able to be used even if the local computer does not have the file (I.E. it should be in files with the application).

so far haven't done a whole lot to trying to get it to work as I have been busy. I do have it opening based on file location for the Excel workbook so far but is not the end goal I am wanting if possible. I am working on this with multiple machines and so I have project file on a flash drive but if I work on it on a different machine the flash drive does have the same root directory name so then it doesn't work. Can I make it a item or something in visual studio so it doesn't need a file location other than the project location to open and modify?

```
 //open workbook.
      oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(@"[workbook file location here]"));
      oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
```

Comment: Just add the file to your project with Project > Add Existing item.  Set its Copy to Output Directory property as "Copy if newer".

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file to your project. Either as content or as part of a resource.

**As Content**

1. Right click your project
2. Select 'Add existing item'
3. Choose the Excel file
4. Right click the added Excel file
5. Select 'Properies'
6. Choose 'Content' as build type
7. Choose 'Copy if newer'

**As Resource**

I like the resource approach because it makes it easy to access the file later on in your project.

1. Right click your project
2. Select 'Add item'
3. Search for 'Resource'
4. Open the added file and choose 'Files' for the types
5. Add your Excel file with Drag & Drop to the resource
6. Now you are able to access the file in C# from `Resources.Name_of_your_Excel_File`

Comment: Is there a way to make the Excel file open and modify to save as later when its a resource?

Comment: I have only used the excel files as templates and never tried to write them back to the resource file. I guess it might be possible with a ResXResourceWriter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically